# ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre jquery y javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Me interesa saber cuáles son las diferencias entre jquery y javascript y cuál es el más conveniente usar para un poyecto web profesional.

Comment: Te recomiendo que para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida te des una vuelta por [ask].

Comment: La deferencia es que jquery te hace el trabajo mas fácil, aunque por experiencia te recomiendo aprender javascript. Pues ya teniendo previo conocimiento en javascript te sera mas fácil usar librerías basadas en javascript, como ecmascript, babel, etc, etc.

Comment: JavaScript es el lenguaje de programación, que esta presente en los navegadores web y jquery es una librería escrita o basada en dicho lenguaje que surgió por la necesidad de hacer tareas como las peticiones AJAX simples y compatibles en todos los navegadores; generalmente hacer uso de JavaScript es mas rápido que depender de una librería pero depende del escenario si vas a requerir resolver tareas complejas puedes usarla, sin embargo te comento que el propio JQuey reconoce que ahora es mas simple hacer todo lo que antes motivo su nacimiento como las peticiones AJAX

Comment: Javascript es un lenguaje de programación. jQuery es una librería escrita en Javascript. No son cosas comparables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero veamos que es cada cosa:

**jQuery**:

> jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes
>   things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling,
>   animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works
>   across a multitude of browsers. With a combination of versatility and
>   extensibility, jQuery has changed the way that millions of people
>   write JavaScript.

Copiado de la web oficial de jQuery. Básicamente, por si alguien anda mal con el inglés, lo que nos dicen es que jQuery es una biblioteca o librería rápida, pequeña y con muchas funcionalidades. Permite manipular el DOM, manejar eventos, animaciones y Ajax de manera mas simple con una API que funciona en multitud de navegadores(ojo, multitud no son todos). Combinando versatilidad y extensibilidad (por traducirlo de manera que se pueda entender) ha cambiado la forma en la que mucha gente escribe JavaScript.

Básicamente te dicen que estás usando JavaScript, pero con atajos y cositas que te hacen mas fácil usar JavaScript.

Ahora veamos **JS**:

> JavaScript (abreviado comúnmente JS) es un lenguaje de programación
>   interpretado, dialecto del estándar ECMAScript. Se define como
>   orientado a objetos,3​ basado en prototipos, imperativo, débilmente
>   tipado y dinámico.
>
> Se utiliza principalmente en su forma del lado del cliente
>   (client-side), implementado como parte de un navegador web permitiendo
>   mejoras en la interfaz de usuario y páginas web dinámicas4​ aunque
>   existe una forma de JavaScript del lado del servidor (Server-side
>   JavaScript o SSJS). [...] Desde el 2012, todos los navegadores
>   modernos soportan completamente ECMAScript 5.1, una versión de
>   javascript. Los navegadores más antiguos soportan por lo menos
>   ECMAScript 3. La sexta edición se liberó en julio del 2015.5​

Esto sacado de la [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)

Así que por un lado tienes JavaScript puro, que requiere de ciertos comandos extensos y difíciles de recordar y, por otro lado, jQuery, que hace lo mismo, pero con comandos mas sencillos, normalmente son atajos o shorthands de los comandos estandar de JS, metidos en funciones dentro de la librería que te bajas e instalas.

Puede parecer que, a priori, es mejor jQuery, puesto que hace lo mismo que JS pero los comandos son mas sencillos y es mas fácil de recordar y te diré que sí, que lo es.

Ahora bien, **OJO CUIDAO**, que no todos los navegadores son compatibles con los eventos que jQuery tiene, y es posible que alguno te pegue un susto, pues tu web no se vea en ese navegador, sin tu saber porqué pasa eso. Si buscas llegar a un público que puede usar navegadores antiguos (IE9-) como un ministerio, que sus webs solo se ven en IE, escribe en JS, si por el contrario es para un sector reciente, que se maneja con navegadores tipo Chrome, Mozilla, Opera... Usa jQuery, por comodidad para ti y limpieza del código.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda y no olvides nunca consultar en que navegadores son compatibles los eventos que quieras utilizar, te ahorrarás mucho sufrimiento.

Answer (score -4):

Éste enlace lo explica bastante bien: https://blog.udemy.com/jquery-vs-javascript-2-cual-es-la-diferencia-en-definitiva/
Espero que te ayude

Comment: Un link puede caducar o romperse. Te recomiendo hacer una breve explicación o resumen del contenido para ser considerado buena respuesta :)